# Files not getting listed from google cloud storage when the folder has space between the words

Tags: laravel, google-cloud-platform, filesystems, google-cloud-storage, storage

I am using **Laravel 5.6** and trying to list all the files inside the folder name 2D-3D Shapes.

When I run `Storage::files('images/shapes/2D-3D Shapes')` in **tinker** result is empty but in Google Cloud Storage there are files.
All the files are listed for folder without having space but its problem when the folder has space.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: could you share how are you doing the query to Cloud Storage? Are you escaping the space?

Comment: I am using league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3 package for listing resources of bucket.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the [Bucket and object naming guidelines](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/Filenameencodingandinteroperabilityproblems) documentation you should not use spaces in the naming of your files in Google Cloud Storage. This may lead to interoperability problems with the API. You should also avoid using any special character as the best practice.

To get the files if the name has any special character when calling for the files the name needs to be URI encoded as explained in [request endpoints](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/request-endpoints)

Comment: Thanks Chris we are not using any spaces for the new folder but this issue is for the folders which were already created (at that time we were using ckeditor) and we are in such situation that if we remove the space then link of thousands images will get broken.

Comment: To get the files when they include special characters or spaces these characters must be escaped as explained in [Request Endpoints](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/request-endpoints)